# Import trait from another file

Tags: scala

I have a file called `Model.scala` which begins with the following lines:

```
package chess

trait Content
```

In the same directory, I have another file called `Board.scala` that starts with the following:

```
package chess

import chess.Content
```

However, in `Board.scala`, I am getting this error:

```
Error:(3, 8) object Content is not a member of package chess
import chess.Content
       ^
```

So how can I import a `Trait` from another file?

Comment: If they're in the same package, as in this case, you don't have to import anything. It's a common practice to put classes in different files.

Comment: If I don't import anything, I get `not found: type Content`

Comment: What do you do to compile these files?

Comment: as @handler pointed out, it would share some new light if you gave as a complete project structure and build.sbt

Comment: Don't import chess.Contetn, just make sure to compile Model.scala before compiling Board.scala

Answer (score 1):

the location of files shouldn't matter, and when two files have the same package (in your case "chess"), both traits/classes should be in scope. since this does not appear to be working for you, my guess is that you are trying to run this outside of sbt.

can you update to show what your project structure is, and if you have it, the `build.sbt` file?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I am ramping up on scala myself and may find the answer you were looking for.

If your trait and class in Board.scala are in the same package, you don't need to import.
If you ran into this error in IntelliJ Idea using SBT, maybe you need to resync your SBT.

Also, your Board.scala class should probably have 'with' for using the trait (instead of import) like this:

```
class Board extends App with Content {
```